# Making the C# compiler aware that a null-oblivious method may return null?

Tags: c#, automapper, nullability

AutoMapper's `T IMapper.Map<T>(object)` is null-oblivious for [historical reasons](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1302#issuecomment-221321838). If you pass `null`, the result is `null`. The C# compiler does not warn about the possible null return when returning the result of `Map` from a method declared to return `T`.

Is there a way to make the compiler treat `Map` as if it had been declared as `T? IMapper.Map<T>(object?)`? I thought about wrapping `IMapper` in a different interface and injecting that instead, but that seems a bit heavy-handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`MaybeNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullattribute) attribute.

The Microsoft documentation uses this example:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public T Find<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

> The preceding code informs callers that the return value *may* actually
> be null. It also informs the compiler that the method may return a
> `null` expression even though the type is non-nullable.

From [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

---

Obviously, since the type is from an external library, you can only apply the attribute yourself by modifying the external source code.

You should ask the developers to add the attribute in a future version.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4173), but of course it was immediately closed and brushed off without explanation. I think it's time to fork Automapper.